# Google iosched: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in

Tags: iosched

3 weeks back, I had Google iosched source downloaded and imported into my android studio. I could install & run the app in my emulator as well as my devices connected to my machine. However, last week, when I tried to run the same Android Studio project, I have started getting "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. - com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException".

Android SDK Tools - 23.0.5
Android SDK Platform-tools - 21
Android SDK Build-tools - 21.1.1
Android 5.0 (API 21) - SDK Platform Rev 1
ARM EABI v7s System Image - Rev 1

I tried to make changes as recommended in [Configuring Your App for Multidex with Gradle](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)
but no luck.

**android/build.gradle:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'<br>
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

But I started getting the below exception.

A problem occurred evaluating project ':android'.

> Could not find method multiDexEnabled() for arguments [true] ...

I am not clear how can an app project that was running well couple weeks before can get into this kind of problem? What could have changed and where am I going wrong? Someone pls help me.

Note: In the same machine & Android Studio, I have one of our own apps which continues to run without any problem. it's target Sdk Version was 19. I could change it to 21 and run it on devices/emulator running from android ICS to Android L.

Answer (score 0):

**multiDexEnabled** property configured in Gradle plugin.
In your main build.gradle file, make sure that its version is at least 0.14.0:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
    }
}
```