# appcompat-v7:22.1.0 not working

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

If i write in my gradle file this code

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    }
```

all work cool. but if i change

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
```

my app crash. Android studio recomended me change version to `22.1.0` but if i chage version - crash.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\zen_75\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\projects\android-customer\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\projects\android-customer\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

how do I fix it or leave it?

EDIT:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
}
```

i change file - not work!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when i include gradle's library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839332/error-when-i-include-gradles-library)

Comment: You're in for a trip.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue updating to latest appcompat and support library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/issue-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-library)

Comment: @Yurets it is not a duplicate. since I solved this problem. and in this regard I ask why not work this version

Comment: i add multiDexEnabled true it not helped! and in your link, problem with 21.0.2

Comment: @ip696 check my answer for how to use multidex correctly

Answer (score 1):

You have `Over 65K Methods` in you project, seems like Google has add a lot of now methods to the `appcomapt-v21.1` libs.

Anyway, For now you have those options:
 1. Use `Multidex`, Follow the instructions below, more info [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)
 2. Use the `ProGuard`
 3. Cut down the number of methods you have in your project

**You have to keep in mind:**

- `Multidex` may not work on devices running Android v3.x-, check all limitations [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#limitations)
- `ProGuard` is not guaranteed to solve the problem
- Re-write you code to cut down the number of methods is not easy.

**Add multidex support:**

*build.gradle*

```
android {
    ...
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ...
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  ...
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:+'
}
```

*manifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="x.xxx.xx">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**PS:** You can count the number of methods you have in your project using [dex-method-counts](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts), it will give you a clear idea about your situation.

Comment: Considering `Multidex` support is only 4.0+ in a reliable manner, I don't think that's a valid option.

Comment: I have 4 moduls with gradle feles too. Shall I do the same thing in them, or only in the main module?

Comment: nothing helps. stupid android. left version appcompat-v7:22.0.0

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to start using ProGuard's `minify` capability. Please note that it breaks `Dagger` dependency injection over version 1.0.1.

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Test your application extensibly, as this removes unused methods, and does many other things.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html